# Submit Credit Card payment missing after update

Tags: 4.7, paypal, upgrade

our non-profit uses civiCRM. Recently we updated from version 4.5.5 to 4.7.16

The update caused the an important option to disappear. On the contributions category the option "Submit Credit Card contribution" was available before our update next to the line "Click Record Contribution to record a new contribution received from this contact."

Currently, we are not able to charge CC of a donor without having to go and do that via paypal. I do not think this has anything to do with "paypal pro" as the option was available to us before the civiCRM update.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue also in Drupal, after upgrading from 4.7.15 to 4.7.27 and what I found was that it was a caching issue. I needed to delete everything *inside* the `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c` directory.